# How can I transfer the Gamestate from IOS to Android

Tags: bloons-td-5

I switched from iOS to Android and I want to keep my progress in this game.

How can I achieve this? Facebook connection did not help

Comment: Just a guess, but if they use the same save file, you should be able to manually copy the iOS save file (probably need a jailbroken phone) over to Android (might not need a rooted phone?), into the proper directories.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android and Apple devices currently do not natively communicate between each other, the save game feature transfer between the platforms will be entirely dependent on developer support.

The only feasible option is to ask the developer if such feature is available.